# Why my `Selector` always return same `SelectionKey` in java NIO?

Tags: java, kotlin, nio

My NetSelector class:

```
    class NetSelector(
        private var selector: Selector,
        private val emptySelectThreshold: Int
    ) : NetSelector {

        private var keyIterator: MutableIterator<SelectionKey> = emptyKeyIterator
        private var lastEmptySelectTime: Long = 0L
        private var emptySelectCount: Int = 0

        private var isClose = false

        override fun next(): SelectionKey {
            if (keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                val next = keyIterator.next()
                keyIterator.remove()
                println("next>>>>>>>> $next")
                return next
            }
            var selectCount = selector.select()
            println("selectCount>>>>>>>>> $selectCount")
            while (selectCount == 0) {
                val now = epochMillis()
                if (now == lastEmptySelectTime) {
                    emptySelectCount++
                    if (emptySelectCount >= emptySelectThreshold) {
                        //High CPU if select count is always 0
                        emptySelectCount = 0
                        rebuildSelector()
                        return next()
                    } else {
                        selectCount = selector.select()
                    }
                } else {
                    lastEmptySelectTime = now
                    emptySelectCount = 0
                    selectCount = selector.select()
                }
            }
            val selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys()
            keyIterator = selectedKeys.iterator()
            return next()
        }

        private fun rebuildSelector() {
            val newSelector = Selector.open()
            for (key in selector.keys()) {
                if (!key.isValid || key.interestOps() == 0) {
                    continue
                }
                key.cancel()
                val channel = key.channel()
                val attachment = key.attachment()
                channel.register(newSelector, key.interestOps(), attachment)
                selector.selectNow()
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                selector.close()
                selector = newSelector
                if (isClose) {
                    newSelector.close()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun close() {
            synchronized(this) {
                selector.close()
                isClose = true
            }
        }

        companion object {
            private val emptyKeyIterator: MutableIterator<SelectionKey> = object : MutableIterator<SelectionKey> {
                override fun hasNext(): Boolean = false
                override fun next(): SelectionKey = throw NoSuchElementException("This iterator is empty!")
                override fun remove() = throw IllegalStateException("This iterator is empty!")
            }
        }
    }
```

It returns same `SelectionKey` when I use `next()` method:

```
selectCount>>>>>>>>> 1
next>>>>>>>> sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@30beb8f5
selectCount>>>>>>>>> 1
next>>>>>>>> sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@30beb8f5
```

**Where is the mistake?**

Comment: If it returns the same SelectionKey, then apparently you didn't do anything to the SelectableChannel. E.g. if there is data to be read, and you didn't read it (all), and you a selector.select, the same SelectionKey is returned. For a write there is a similar problem; as long as you are registered for a write event and there space in the socket buffer, the you will keep getting the SelectionKey for that SelectableChannel; until you deregister for the write event.

Comment: Keep in mind that Selectors in Java are level triggered; not edge triggered.

Comment: @pveentjer I use a listener-thread to read these keys into a queue, and use another executor to consume keys in the queue. What should I do if I don't want to consume keys in listener-thread?

Comment: To difficult to answer :) Which event are you repeatedly getting? So when you get your selection key, print 'isReadable' , 'isWritable' etc. This way you have clue why you are stuck in this loop.

Comment: This is no way to use a selector. You are supposed to open it *once*, then repeatedly call `select()`, iterate the selected keys, removing each, and processing whatever ones are ready. Don't write code like this.

Comment: @user207421 I'm not sure exactly what you are referring to. But the reason he recreates the selector is a workaround due to a bug in JDK's. Netty has a similar fix.

Comment: @pveentjer What bug? I've been using `Selector` for 18 years without encountering any need for such code.

Comment: @user207421 there is some kind of epoll 100% CPU bug. https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/nio/NioEventLoopGroup.java#L114